# Referring to a controller extension in VF remoting

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, controller-extension

I’ve created a class to extend a standard page controller… [(documentation)](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm)

```
<apex:page standardController="location__C" extensions="locationExtension">
```

The class locationExtension contains…

```
public class locationExtension  {     
    static Location__c loc = new Location__c();

    public locationExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        loc = (location__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public static String doSomething () {
    ...
    }
}
```

In my VisualForce, I’m trying to call the doSomething method using…

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.Location__c.doSomething}', ...
```

However, I can't figure out how to reference the doSomething method in the VF remoting call. As you'd expect it wants ControllerName.RemotedMethod.  How do you get this to take the extension into account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your VF page, to call your method you need to do like this :

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.locationExtension.doSomething}', ...
```

And you need to add the `@RemoteAction` tag on your method and modify the class definition :

```
public with sharing class locationExtension {
...

@RemoteAction
public static String doSomething () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help - unfortunately it's giving me a compile error of "No remoted actions found for 'locationextension.doSomething"  I also get a similar error when I try Location__c.doSomething.

Comment: And if you replace `public class locationExtension` by `public with sharing class locationExtension`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Works for me without defining sharing model. Aka: `public class foo { @RemoteAction public static void doSomething () { } }`